# NIST time exception

Tags: java, timestamp

I am trying the following code with Log4J in an applet.  All I get is the creation and I cant trap the error.  I opened a FW rule but it is not even getting that far.

```
try {
    ac00_lfj.debug("NISTtime: query==true: about create NTPUDPClient");
    timeClient = new NTPUDPClient();
  }catch (Exception ex) {
    ac00_lfj.debug("NTUDPclient: creation exception = "+ex.toString());
  }
```

Comment: Applets operate in a security sandbox; I don't think you will be able to ultimately manipulate the system clock (or even write a file) without enormous difficulty - must it be an applet?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch  Thank you, I have gone through all that it is a signed applet and I can read and write files locally as is its use case.  How can I catch an unknown exception?  Just creating the object should allowed, correct?

Comment: Catch `Exception` or `Throwable`; I still don't think you're going to be able to change the system clock.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I believe I am doing that in the code snippet and I get nothing in the Java console.  I am not trying to change the system clock just create the object.  Am I obtuse here?

Comment: Why are you thinking that there is an exception? What do you think instantiating the object (as shown in the code snippet) should do?

Comment: @ElliottFrischI have log4J debug right after this and it never prints, therefore there was a fatal problem instantiating the object, which I expected to leave me with the object in memory so I could call on its methods.

Comment: And what leads you to think that your log4j is working correctly? Do you see any log messages?

Comment: @ElliottFrischBack again.  I was able to make the EXACT same code work on the server but still fails in the applet on the instantiation of the NTPUDPClinet object.  This is signed app and I really need it executing on the client.  Any further ideas.

Comment: Why does it have to be an Applet? I would use [Java Web Start](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javawebstart/index.html).